# Have any palimpsests been found in medieval Icelandic (saga) literature?

Tags: middle-ages, book, writing, iceland, norse-mythology

Old Norse mythology and history are mostly known through Icelandic medieval parchements. Have those been found to include palimpsests, like medieval parchement in Europe has?

Comment: The last quarter of http://www.hurstwic.org/history/articles/literature/text/Manuscripts.htm suggests it was not unknown, citing a couple of cases, one of bookbinding and the other of censorship rather than reuse of vellum.  But remember that Iceland was not the same place as desert monasteries in terms either of culture or of climate.